# How to find a string contains XXX-XXXXXX format? java

Tags: java

I have a user input into a input box and want to find whether user entered the text format like 'XXX-XXXXXX'

How do I do this in java?

Comment: you could use regex.

Comment: You can create a Regex pattern as per need https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ . Then match the string against one .

Comment: Questions are more easily answered if you include some code on what you have. Also, are you looking to enforce this input on like a phone number or login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `split`.

```
String str = "XXX-XXXXXX";
String[] words = str.split("-");
if(words[0].toCharArray().length == 3 && words[1].toCharArray().length == 6 && words.length == 2)
{
    System.out.println("Correct");
}
```

Comment: @KevinEsche, now I think it is OK

Comment: If you include a check for `words.length == 2` then it should be fine even for `XXX` as input.

Comment: @KevinEsche, yeah, that would also work. Edited. Thanks for pointing out the bug.